# Type inference is not happening in polymorphic function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have written 2 version of codes as below . In 1st version , I am getting run time error as below , not able to understand why i am getting error while I am passing Iterator type for function : **using**. Where as in version 2 it is running fine while passing type of Resource type for function : **using** .

> Error:(23, 11) inferred type arguments [Iterator[String],Nothing] do not conform to method using's type parameter bounds [A <: AnyRef{def close(): Unit},B]
>     control.using(Source.fromFile("C:\Users\pswain\IdeaProjects\test1\src\main\resources\employee").getLines){a => {for (line <- a) { println(line)}}}
>             ^

1st version:-

```
  /**
  * Created by PSwain on 9/22/2016.
  */

import java.io.{IOException, FileNotFoundException}

import scala.io.Source

object control {
  def using[ A <: {def close() : Unit},B ] (resource : A) (f: A => B) :B =
  {
    try {

      f(resource)
    } finally {
      resource.close()
    }
  }
}
object fileHandling extends App {


  control.using(Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\pswain\\IdeaProjects\\test1\\src\\main\\resources\\employee").getLines){a => {for (line <- a) { println(line)}}}
}
```

2nd version

```
/**
  * Created by PSwain on 9/22/2016.
  */

import java.io.{IOException, FileNotFoundException}

import scala.io.Source

object control {
  def using[ A <: {def close() : Unit},B ] (resource : A) (f: A => B) :B =
  {
    try {

      f(resource)
    } finally {
      resource.close()
    }
  }
}
object fileHandling extends App {


  control.using(Source.fromFile("C:\\Users\\pswain\\IdeaProjects\\test1\\src\\main\\resources\\employee")){a => {for (line <- a.getLines) { println(line)}}}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first version doesn't compile because you're passing the result of `getLines`, which is of type `Iterator[String]` as the first argument. That argument must have a `def close(): Unit` method (as bounded by `A <: {def close() : Unit}`), and `Iterator[String]` does not have such a method.

The second version works because a `Source` is passed as `A`, which fits the bound (has a matching `close` method)

Comment: Thanks ! I got in now .